# How should I make a move point of 0.1 instead of free move

Tags: modeling

I basically want a set amount of move size like 0.1 instead of 0 which is free move. Also when I try using arrows to move points sometimes it moves it if I were to press g. How do I move it only on the xyz angles.

Comment: Select the object, and go to the extreme right, see the Properties panels.  Select the little cube icon, then open it's Transform tab.  In there are 3 transform panels, each with 3 text slots, one for each axis. (x,y,z)  Left click in any one to enter a figure directly, like 0.001, or 0.1 etc.  You can also use it's handles to step using a default step figure.  You can also slide the values by holding Left MB down and dragging.

Answer (score 2):

You can move an object along its local axes by pressing *<kbd>G</kbd>, Axis, Amount*.
For example <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>

You can an object along it three axis by pressing *<kbd>G</kbd>, X Amount, <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>, Y Amount, <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>, Z Amount*.
For example <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>.

You can move an object perpendicular to the view, by creating a camera (which starts aligned to the view), rotating the camera on the view plane, and moving the object along a cameras axis.

1. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the object and snap the cursor to it <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*Cursor to selected*.
2. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Camera*, to add a camera.
3. <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate it.
4. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>, to move it 0.5 along its local X axis.
5. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to selected*, to snap the cursor to the camera.
6. <kbd>X</kbd> to delete the camera.
7. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> click to select the object.
8. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*

[image: Moving an object along an axis, whcih is perpendicular to the camera]